# Does Chrome support oncanplaythrough for the Audio element?

Tags: google-chrome, html5-audio

I'm using Chrome for Linux, on Ubuntu 12.04, everything is up to date. Chrome doesn't seem to support the oncanplaythrough DOM level 0 event, at least from JavaScript. I've tried creating the audio object with `new Audio()` and `document.createElement('audio')`. The event works in Firefox, like it should, nowhere can i find information that others have the same issue or that this is a problem, so is it a bug? The DOM level 2 'canplaythrough' event works just fine, but i need to be able to clear an anonymous event callback, so that's not really an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

This might have to do with the fact what kind of audio format is and how you serve it.

Different browsers set different requirements how they can deal with the files in the net. For example, HTTP ranged header support might be required or audio file could need to have duration headers set in special way.

I have seen this event fired, so I am pretty sure you can get it, at least under specific conditions.

Maybe you can clarify how do you construct and server the audio file? Maybe a jsfiddle.net repeatable example?

Some background:

http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/ChrisKhoo/20120618/172573/The_HTML5_audio_troubleshooting_guide.php

Comment: The event fires properly if i subscribe using `addEventListener`, so it's not an issue of the server, just there doesn't seem to be an `oncanplaythrough` field on the Audio object at all, there is one in Firefox. In Chrome i don't get auto completion for the field and when accessed it returns `undefined` instead of `null` like with other events. It seems like Chrome is just completely not aware of its existence.